# Appearance of strange lines appearing when plotting an integral

Tags: integration, graphing-functions

While playing around on Desmos, I came across the function $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x+n}{x-n}\right)}{x}$ where $n>0$. I wanted to find the integral between the first and last zeros where $x$ is positive and came up with the bounds $\frac{\pi x-x}{\pi+1}$ and $\frac{\pi x+x}{\pi-1}$. I then decided to plot the integral against $n$ using the equation: $$g\left(x\right)=\int_{\frac{\pi x-x}{\pi+1}}^{\frac{\pi x+x}{\pi-1}}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{t+x}{t-x}\right)}{t}dt$$
Desmos was unable to plot this so I plotted $\left(\left[0.1,0.2...10\right],g\left(\left[0.1,0.2...10\right]\right)\right)$. In Desmos, $[...]$ indicates a set of numbers. I noticed the occurrence of what almost appeared to be lines around $y=0.027$, $y=0.023$, $y=0.02$, and a scattering of points between $y=0.007$ and $y=-0.003$. I then plotted $\left(\left[0.1,0.2...100\right],g\left(\left[0.1,0.2...100\right]\right)\right)$ which seemed to confirm my results. Here is what it looked like:
[image]
Can anybody explain this? Here is the link to the Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/thjmpjqvcx

Comment: Could be numerical errors from trying to integrate across an essential singularity. Also, shouldn't that be an $x$ and not a $t$ in the denominator of the integral?

Comment: Between the first and last zeros where $x$ is positive is, I think, what's going wrong. The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin\frac{x+n}{x-n}}{x}$ is not defined at $x=n$, which is between the integration limits (by the way, it's really confusing to use $x$ in such different ways in your question!). If you look at the function near $x=n$, you'll see it oscillates very rapidly. Whatever numerical method desmos is using (sampling, I guess) is creating this artefact.

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivative is quite simple
$$\frac {t+x}{t-x}=y \implies t=x \frac {y+1}{y-1}\implies dt=-\frac{2 x}{(y-1)^2}\,dy$$
$$I=\int \frac{\sin\left(\frac{t+x}{t-x}\right)}{t}\,dt=-2\int \frac{\sin(y)}{y^2-1}\,dy $$ Partial fraction decomposition and two simple changes of variable lead to
$$I=-\sin (1) (\text{Ci}(1-y)- \text{Ci}(1+y))+\cos (1)
   (\text{Si}(1-y)+\text{Si}(1+y))$$

Back to $x$ and using the bounds
$$g(x)=(\text{Ci}(-1-\pi )+\text{Ci}(1-\pi )-\text{Ci}(-1+\pi )-\text{Ci}(1+\pi)) \sin (1)$$ $$g(x)=2 i \pi  \sin (1)$$

which is a constant and moreover a complex number.

I suppose that this explains that (hoping for no mistake on my side).

**Edit**

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can easily show that $g'(x)=0$ so $g(x)=\text{Cte}$. The details are left to the reader.

Comment: This doesn't actually explain OP's question - why would those lines appear? But I think the issue is that between those bounds, the function blows up (that's why you're getting a complex answer to a real integral). desmos just can't cope and its integration method happens to produce those lines.